# jest not creating snapshot

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, snapshot

i have created a jest test file below.But the snapshot for this file is not  created. What is the issue in my code?

```
import React from 'react';
import Carousel from './component';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

test('Carousel Component Test Suite', () => {

const component = renderer.create(
    <Carousel
       />
);

let tree = component.toJSON();
expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();

});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you done a `console.log` on `tree` to see if it has a value? I cannot see anything particularly wrong in the code. Have you run with `--u` as an argument as that is what updates the snapshot file?

Comment: In console,nothing is printed. Error is cannot read property "0" of undefined. slideIndex is initialised as 0 in the component.

Comment: Not the problem in this case but a .snap file won't be generated unless the test calls toMatchSnapshot or similar.

Answer (score 9):

You have to update the test case. Fire the command below in command prompt/terminal etc.

```
npm test -u YourTest.spec.js
```

Do this in project root directory.

Answer (score 1):

I ran it locally (swapping in a simple component) and it generated a .snap file.

As far as I can see everything looks fine but it may be a problem with a specific version of a dependency you're using (but without seeing your package.json it's impossible to say).